# react-native : determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I want to determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline

im using react native as platform , and the package : react-native-google-maps to provide the map

i did some search and as a result i found this function ' isLocationOnEdge()  ' in Geometry Library of google link :
[Geometry Livrary](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry)
that did the same function as i want
the problém is that i can't implement this function in react-native
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org). I used it in a RN project with `react-native-maps` for geo calculations.

[booleanPointOnLine](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointOnLine) solves part one of your problem (on a line),
[pointToLineDistance](http://turfjs.org/docs/#) solves part two (near a line).

Add to package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6"
}
```

Import in component

```
import { pointToLineDistance } from '@turf/point-to-line-distance';
import { booleanPointOnLine} from '@turf/boolean-point-on-line';
```

Use as described in the docs.